# JavaScript for <body> to only scroll by mousewheel/manual scroll?

Tags: javascript, scroll, mouseevent, anchor, mouselistener

Is there a way to lock the `<body>` element to prevent it from scrolling unless there is a mousewheel/up or dn key/swipe or other manual scrolling action?

I would like to prevent the main part of the webpage from autoscrolling/jumping when an anchor tag is clicked.

Comment: Maybe you could have the links have an onclick event handler and handle the links as you want to, but then prevent the default event from bubbling up?

Comment: Look at the css rules for position:fixed and position:absolute if you want to keep certain parts of your page always onscreen.